# How to remove index.php from opencart home page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I have enabled seo url in opencart settings. I have also return .htaccess file. But still index.php in coming at the end of the home page. Once I click on the home page it comes blank untill I write index.php after the DNS. Please if any one can help me where I am going wrong with the things.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have checked number of links but not getting the correct output. Still the home page is blank. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

To remove index.php, you can do replace in this file

`/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Find:

```
return $link;
```

Before it on a new line put:

```
$link = str_replace('index.php?route=common/home', '', $link);
```

Edit If you want full SEO just use this line instead of the above:

```
$link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
```

Also make sure SEO URLs is turned on in the Admin panel of the store.

Related:

Comment: I have already done that. But still the result is same as previous.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing is weird and I am unable to help you just fix it because I don't have much detail.

I think, first of all you should check your error logs, if there are any new errors share them here.

I think, home page may have some kind of errors when you visit without index.php in URL. Because of those errors site won't may be working correctly & showing the blank page on your home page. Enable the Error Display & check if there are any errors displayed then post the errors here.

[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Cheers.